# Largura do input Bootstrap usando form-inline

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3

Eu tenho um `form-inline` em bootstrap, como eu controlo o **width** do **input** sem perder a responsividade?

Exemplo [w3schools form-inline bootstrap](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_form_inline&stacked=h)

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="email">Email:</label>
  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
```

Eu já tentei `style="width: 300px"` no input e funciona, aumenta o tamanho do campo, mas perde a responsividade, eu já tentei colocar o `<div class="form-group">` dentro de uma tag `<div class="col-sm-5">`, pois dessa forma um `form-horizontal` funciona, ou seja, só não funciona no `form-inline`

Resumindo, eu quero exatamente a funcionalidade de um `form inline` , o único problema é que não consigo controlar o `width` dos inputs sem perder a responsividade.

Comment: Eu não sei se entendi bem a tua pergunta, mas pelo que percebi o que queres fazer aqui é dar um `width:300px;` à input - `<input class="form-control" />` para ser o seu tamanho inicial, mas ao mesmo tempo não perder a sua responsividade é isso?

Comment: Isso, porém eu sei que se eu especificar o `width:300px;` sei que perde a responsividade, ou seja, o certo mesmo seria especificar o tamanho da coluna, mas isso não faz efeito quando usa o `form-inline`

Comment: Coloca o `form` dentro de um `<div class="row"> </div> ` e depois coloca um `<div class="col-md-4"></div>` fora dos `inputs` (inclusive o `button`). Substitua o 4 por o tamanho que você quer, lembrando que a soma têm que dar 12.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simples, podes fazer isto utilizando a propriedade `min-width` no teu CSS:

```
.form-control{min-width:300px;}
```

ou implementando-o directamente no HTML:

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" style="min-width:300px;" placeholder="Enter email">
```

Aqui tens um exemplo online no jsFiddle: <kbd>http://jsfiddle.net/74sgvd5h/</kbd>

A propriedade `min-width` é usada para definir a largura mínima de um elemento. Isto evita que o valor `width` se torne menor do que a largura minima - `min-width`.
Podes ler mais sobre esta propriedade em [CSS min-width Property - w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-width.asp).

Comment: Funcionou! era exatamente isso que eu queria! Obrigado Chun

Comment: De nada @RodrigoRodrigues , sempre às ordens! ;)

Answer (score -2):

Você pode utilizar porcentagem em vez de pixels.

Ex: style="min-width:50%;"

Comment: **`1º`** - Porquê ou como é que o uso de **Percentagem** em vez de **Pixeis** iria resolver o problema? **`2º`** - Isto basicamente é uma cópia da minha resposta apenas usando percentagem em vez de pixeis. A não ser que quisesses publicar isto como um comentário na minha resposta e não como uma nova resposta, esta resposta não faz muito sentido. Pelo menos a parte que não é código.